# Word DOCX table transformation via HTML

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to transform a table which is in the word docx document but i dont know how to put elements inside the table in the same way.I share the part of the XML code :

```
<w:tbl>
        <w:tblPr>
            <w:tblStyle w:val="TableGrid"/>
            <w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/>
            <w:tblLook w:val="04A0" w:firstRow="1" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:noHBand="0" w:noVBand="1"/>
        </w:tblPr>
        <w:tblGrid>
            <w:gridCol w:w="950"/>
            <w:gridCol w:w="1631"/>
            <w:gridCol w:w="963"/>
            <w:gridCol w:w="736"/>
            <w:gridCol w:w="950"/>
            <w:gridCol w:w="924"/>
            <w:gridCol w:w="883"/>
            <w:gridCol w:w="1685"/>
        </w:tblGrid>
        <w:tr w:rsidR="00090366" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidTr="006623B3">
            <w:tc>
                <w:tcPr>
                    <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/>
                </w:tcPr>
                <w:p w:rsidR="00090366" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidRDefault="00090366" w:rsidP="0031172A">
                    <w:pPr>
                        <w:spacing w:line="360" w:lineRule="auto"/>
                        <w:rPr>
                            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
                            <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                            <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
                        </w:rPr>
                    </w:pPr>
                </w:p>
            </w:tc>
            <w:tc>
                <w:tcPr>
                    <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/>
                </w:tcPr>
                <w:p w:rsidR="00090366" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidRDefault="00090366" w:rsidP="0031172A">
                    <w:pPr>
                        <w:spacing w:line="360" w:lineRule="auto"/>
                        <w:rPr>
                            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
                            <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                            <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
                        </w:rPr>
                    </w:pPr>
                </w:p>
            </w:tc>
            <w:tc>
                <w:tcPr>
                    <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/>
                    <w:gridSpan w:val="6"/>
                </w:tcPr>
                <w:p w:rsidR="00090366" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidRDefault="00090366" w:rsidP="00433BB0">
                    <w:pPr>
                        <w:spacing w:line="360" w:lineRule="auto"/>
                        <w:rPr>
                            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
                            <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                            <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
                        </w:rPr>
                    </w:pPr>
                    <w:r w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
                        <w:rPr>
                            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
                            <w:b/>
                            <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                            <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
                        </w:rPr>
                        <w:t>ABC</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                </w:p>
            </w:tc>
        </w:tr>
        <w:tr w:rsidR="00090366" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidTr="006623B3">
            <w:tc>
                <w:tcPr>
                    <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/>
                    <w:gridSpan w:val="2"/>
                </w:tcPr>
                <w:p w:rsidR="00090366" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidRDefault="00FC507E" w:rsidP="0031172A">
                    <w:pPr>
                        <w:spacing w:line="360" w:lineRule="auto"/>
                        <w:rPr>
                            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
                            <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                            <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
                        </w:rPr>
                    </w:pPr>
                    <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:rPr>
                            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
                            <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                            <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
                        </w:rPr>
                        <w:t>Burak</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                    <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:rPr>
                            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
                            <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                            <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
                        </w:rPr>
                        <w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t>
                    </w:r>
                    <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:rPr>
                            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
                            <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                            <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
                        </w:rPr>
                        <w:t>Kilic</w:t>
                       </w:r>
                    <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
                    <w:r w:rsidR="00090366" w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
                        <w:rPr>
                            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
                            <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                            <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
                        </w:rPr>
                        <w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t>
                    </w:r>
                </w:p>
            </w:tc>
            </w:tr>
            </w:tbl>
```

This is my Basic XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table width="400" cellpadding="1" border="1">


                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>    <xsl:apply-templates select="w:document/w:body/w:tbl"/></td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Desired result is :[image]

I want to know how to order the elements in this way and create the rows and columns like this.it doesnt have to be in the same way but i just need ideas how to do it with XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently selecting `w:tbl` elements, so you need a template to match that, where you output the containing `<table>` tag.

From looking at your input sample, `w:tr` elements correspond to table rows, and `w:tc` correspond to table cells, so you need to select and match these with templates too.

Try this XSLT as a starter

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:w="w">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//w:tbl"/>

            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="w:tbl">
        <table width="400" cellpadding="1" border="1">
            <tbody>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="w:tr"/>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="w:tr">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="w:tc"/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="w:tc">
        <td>
            <xsl:if test="w:tcPr/w:gridSpan">
                <xsl:attribute name="colspan" select="w:tcPr/w:gridSpan/@w:val" />
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select=".//w:t" separator="" />
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note how the code handles the `colspan` attribute. You will need to add a similar condition for creating `rowspan` attribute (You current XML sample is abridged and doesn't contain any row spans, although your output suggests there are some).

Comment: Thank you i needed to know how to read gridSpan`s value from the XML it works perfectly.